# mismatched input 'from' in rule

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am setting up a project to take in a decision table as input and create the rules. 
**Error encountered is "mismatched input 'from' in rule".**

Fact set is :

```
Class Member{
double salary;
List<Tag> tagList;
string ruleResult;
}

Class Tag{
string key;
string value;
}
```

Decision table:

```
-----------------------------------------
|| Condition || Condition||
-----------------------------------------
m:Member()
tg:Tag() from tagList
-----------------------------------------
|| key==$param    || salary >$1 && salary <$2
-----------------------------------------
|| Tag Conditon   || sal condition || 
-----------------------------------------
|| "key1"         || 1000,2000     || 
-----------------------------------------
```

I didnt find much documentation on usage of "from". Any help here to proceed further is greatly appreciated.

### DRL example: ( I am expecting this as the output for the rule)

```
rule "drl_rule"
    salience 65535
    when
        m:Member(tg:tagList,salary>1000 && salary<2000)
        Tag(key=="key1", value=="value1") from tg
    then
        m.setRuleResult("Rule Result1");
end
```